# validating a model in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a django model w/ custom validation code.  When I use django-rest-framework to try and create/update the model, the validation code does get run, but rather than output some JSON w/ error content it fails w/ a ValidationError.  Why doesn't django-rest-framework catch that error?

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  is_default = models.BooleanField()
  type = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=[("a","a"), ("b","b"), ("c","c")]

  def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # there can be only 1 "default" model per type
    if self.is_default:
      other_models = MyModel.objects.filter(
        type=self.type, 
        default=True).exclude(pk=self.pk)
      if other_models.count() != 0:
        raise ValidationError({"default": "There can be only one default model per type.")
    super(MyModel, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'default', 'type')
```

When I try to POST JSON data where type="d", I correctly get the following response:  `{ "type": ["this is not one of the valid choices"]}`.

But when I try to POST JSON data where default=true (and there are already default models of the same type in the db), I just get the ValidationError raised instead of the nicely formatted JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first validation error works because DRFs raises it.

Only subclasses of DRFs own `APIException` are raised inside the framework. So you need to used it's `APIException` class to rise the error.

For example,

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

class CustomException(APIException):

    status_code = 400
    default_detail = 'There can be only one default model per type.'
```

Then you could do this in your model.

```
 if other_models.count() != 0:
     raise CustomException()
```

**On a side note** why are you are trying to create a `unique together` constraint on the model using code? You should do this as the database level using [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

For example, on the model you could do something like this...

```
 class Meta:
     unique_together = ("is_default", "type")
```

Once you have run migrations it will consider them unique when together!

Comment: Regarding unique_together, this is just some sample code.  Strictly speaking, it isn't unique_together, because I allow multiple models with the same type where "default" is True.

Comment: I have just tried raising a django-rest-framework specific error as you suggested.  This does work, and I am marking it as the accepted answer, thanks.  But It does seem wrong somehow to mix the drf code w/ the model definition itself.

Comment: Then raise it in the DRFs create/update method it will work the same. Or in your view on is_valid is etc.

Comment: Good advice.  I've wrapped create/update in a try/catch block and returned a DRF error for every Django error.  Thanks for the quick responses.