# Is it possible to merge a Model/Form validator in Django-Rest-Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, validationerror

I've noticed that [Django form and model validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/) should raise a `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError`, which is an immediate subclass of `Exception`.

In [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/), however, my validator is expected to raise `rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError`, which is **not** a descendant of Django's (it derives from `rest_framework.exceptions.APIException(Exception)`).

Keeping myself DRY, how can I write a validator once, and use it in both, say, Django forms and a DRF serializer?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573338/validating-a-model-in-django-rest-framework) is a related question where DRF does not catch a Django core `ValidationError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using django==1.8 and DRF==3.3.2 and I've just written custom validator in my project and have noticed that both django.core and restframework's ValidationError exceptions works equally fine in DRF. I think this is due to this code in rest_framework.fields:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError as DjangoValidationError
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
...
def run_validators(self, value):
    """
    Test the given value against all the validators on the field,
    and either raise a `ValidationError` or simply return.
    """
    errors = []
    for validator in self.validators:
        if hasattr(validator, 'set_context'):
            validator.set_context(self)

        try:
            validator(value)
        except ValidationError as exc:
            # If the validation error contains a mapping of fields to
            # errors then simply raise it immediately rather than
            # attempting to accumulate a list of errors.
            if isinstance(exc.detail, dict):
                raise
            errors.extend(exc.detail)
        except DjangoValidationError as exc:
            errors.extend(exc.messages)
    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)
```

As you can see, both exceptions can be caught by DRF, so you can use django.core.exceptions.ValidationError in both django forms and DRF.

Comment: Sweet :). not for the first time - reading the code beats reading the docs.